# Simplifying a fraction by only multiplying one side by the denominator?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

Given the problem: $x\sqrt{3} = 6$

We can solve it this way:

$ x = \frac{ 6 } {\sqrt{3} } \times \frac{ \sqrt{3} } { \sqrt{3} } $

$ x = \frac{ 6 \sqrt{3} } {3} $

$ x = 2 \sqrt{3} $

In the first step, why can we multiply only the right side by $\sqrt{3}$? Shouldn't both sides be modified in the same way to keep them balanced?

Comment: At which point exactly do you think that only the right-hand side is multiplied with $\sqrt 3$?

Comment: You can also write $$x\sqrt 3 \times\sqrt 3 =6\times \sqrt3 \\3x=6\sqrt 3 \\ x=2\sqrt3 $$ Or $$x\times \frac{\sqrt 3}{\sqrt 3}=\frac {6}{\sqrt 3}\times \frac{\sqrt 3}{\sqrt 3}\\ x\times 1=x=\cdots $$

Comment: More generally, you have $x = 6 \cdot (3)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$. This means you have $x = 6 \cdot (3)^m \cdot (3)^n$ with any $m,n$ such that $m + n = -\frac{1}{2}$. In this case, you have $m = \frac{1}{2}$, and n = $-1$

Comment: D'oh! For some reason I was thinking it was sqrt(3)/1 instead of exactly what I wrote: sqrt(3)/sqrt(3).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn’t multiply by $\sqrt{3}$; you multiplied by $$\frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{3}}=1$$

This is an extremely common trick in simplifying fractions; multiplying by another fraction where the numerator and denominator are the same, because that fraction is $1$. Multiplying sides by $1$ doesn’t change the equality.

Comment: Indeed, when we "cancel" the $5$'s in $\frac{5}{5\times 2}=\frac{1}{2}$, what we are actually doing is multiplying by $1$:
$$
\frac{5}{5\times 2}=\frac{5}{5\times 2}\times\frac{\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)}{\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)}=\frac{1}{2} \, .
$$

Answer (score 0):

To get from here:

$x\sqrt{3} = 6$

to here:

$ x = \frac{ 6 } {\sqrt{3} } \times \frac{ \sqrt{3} } { \sqrt{3} }, $

both sides of the equation were divided by $\sqrt{3},$ not multiplied by $\sqrt{3}.$